# Bing is not crawling and indexing my mobile subdomain

Tags: robots.txt, bing, crawl-errors

**BACKGROUND**

I have a mobile site located at a sub-domain of m.hydro-cleansing.com. The site is working fine and can be accessed. I am using a search API provided by Bing that should perform a site specific search. The code is working fine when I change the line site:m.hydro-cleansing.com to site:hydro-cleansing.com.

**PROBLEM**

Deducing the problem that the search api isn't performing the necessary search on the site, the issue must lie in the fact that Bing has not crawled the site.

I have looked at the logs for the site and the webmaster tools. Bing has successfully verified the site and found the sitemap.xml file located for the site. I have looked at the robot.txt file for both hydro-cleansing.com and m.hydro-cleansing.com and all is okay. The logs suggest Bing has visited the site ... only to get the sitemap.xml and verfication file.

I am stumped as to what the problem can be, I have read something about it doing with sub-domains but a quick check on m.facebook.com yields a positive result.

Comment: Can you make sure that Bing can crawl both pages by using the  [Fetch as Bingbot](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/fetch-as-bingbot-fe18fa0d) feature in Bing Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Yes fetching as bingbot completes successfully. I am unsure as to why it doesn't work properly so I am in correspondence with Microsoft's Bing team to sort this problem out.

Comment: Do you link to the subdomain?